# Оптимизация кода Изменение стилей с HTML в CSS

Tags: html, css

Доброе время суток.
Такой вопрос касательно верстки и оптимизации.
На странице есть блок который отображается только в мобильной версии сайта.
На десктопной версии он display:none.
Решил что будет не плохой идеей вписать дисплей нон к этому блоку на HTML файле

```html
<div class="mobbody" style="display:none">
....
</div>
```

Вопрос следующий: Как перекрыть дисплей нон?
Через медиа-запрос(вьюпорт есть) поменять display:none на к примеру display:flex/block и т.п.
В прописанном медиа-запросе при размере экрана меньше (условно) 720px 
стиль не присваивается даже с использованием !important.
Возможно я подхожу не с той стороны. Пожалуйста подскажите

Comment: мб поможет: [Override element.style using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910608/override-element-style-using-css)

Comment: Не `!importante`, а `!important`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильно пишется !important и это должно сработать. Но это не лучший вариант - писать стили напрямую в html, а также использовать !important не рекомендуется. Лучше пропишите display: none для стандартного изображения в css-файле, а в медиа-запросе для мобильных display: flex/block